# Filtering and updating options in select dynamically with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have different `<select>` in a *ng-repeat div*.
What I want is to avoid users select several times a same option.

I used the filter like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in datas.customers">
    <select ng-model="customer.attributeId" ng-change="updateCustomer(customer)">
      <option ng-repeat="attribute in datas.attributes | filter:filterByAttributeNotUsed(customer)" value="{{attribute.id}}">{{attribute.name}}</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
```

The filter works like I want (I tested it separately). But the result is not good.

When the filter is active, options in different select have to show only "free" attributes (it means, attributes which are not yet selected).

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Stalyon/xzbxqf94/1/) which is more explicit I suppose.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. What do you mean by "the result is not good"? Perhaps show what you are getting and what you are expecting to get.